# Align Items Inside Top Navigation

Tags: css, master-page, branding

Sorry the (what I believe is) very basic question.
I am in doing (trying to do) some branding in our company's intranet site, which uses SPS2013. The site is a publishing site.

I posted the two questions I wanted to ask in the illustration attached.
I am sorry I am not allowed to share the real site screenshots.
I can post the codes, though, if necessary.

[image]

If my question is obscure or lack information, please let me know. I am a long time SPS user but new to branding it. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: I wanted also to add that I want to achieve this by:  -Using CSS only (ideally)  -Using CSS and jQuery or JS (if the above is not possible) - Modifying master pages  (if the above both are not possible. In this case, I'll be very glad if I could get a more step-by-step-like explanation)

Answer (score 1):

You can play around on below mentioned CSS selectors:

```
// to Hide the page Title

.ms-core-pageTitle{
   display: None !important;
}

// change the size of breadcrumb

.ms-breadcrumb-box{
    background-color: #1a5276 ;
    height: 0px !important;

}

// change the Top navigation color, size , location


.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox li.static > .ms-core-listMenu-item{
    color: White !important;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

//modify the search box

.ms-mpSearchBox{
    background-color: #1a5276;
    padding-top: 3 px !important;
    padding-left: 3 px;
}

#searchInputBox{
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
}

.ms-srch-sb-border{
    border: 2px solid white;
}

.ms-helperText, input.ms-helperText{
    color: white !important;
}
```

You can put this css altogether in script editor and add it on your page.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the proposed answer. It seems I wasn't clear enough about what I wanted to achieve, so I edited my previous post adding another graphic illustrating what I looks now and what I want it to look like. Hope this helps understanding what I need.

Comment: Hi Jim, My answer is same, you can play around with given CSS selector and added my demo image in my previous post..

Comment: Thank you! Can I clarify two things? 1) Because I wanted each item in my menu to look button-like, I added some CSS/jQuery. But when I do that, because of the background-color and border lines, it becomes clear that the text (green) is not centralized to its container (orange). How can I centralized the text here?  2) In the image you provided we can see that we have exactly what I have now (as in my illustration above). Do you have idea how we can stretch the ms-breadcrumb-top so the HOME (in your image) goes to the far left and the other items are distributed along the page?